# Why is the second type of a Zipper a list of data not not pure data?

Tags: haskell, zipper

I made my way thru the Tutorial available at [Learn your Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers)
and I ask myself why the Author uses a list as the second type for the implemented Zipper?

Here is the relevant Code:

```hs
type Name = String
type Data = String
data FSItem = File Name Data
    | Folder Name [FSItem]
    deriving (Show)

data FSCrumb = FSCrumb Name [FSItem] [FSItem]
    deriving (Show)
type FSZipper = (FSItem, [FSCrumb])

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Some other code he uses
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

fsUp :: FSZipper -> FSZipper
fsUp (item, FSCrumb name ls rs : bs) = (Folder name (ls ++ [item] ++ rs), bs)

fsTo :: Name -> FSZipper -> FSZipper
fsTo name (Folder folderName items, bs) =
    let (ls, item:rs) = break (nameIs name) items
    in  (item, FSCrumb folderName ls rs:bs)

nameIs :: Name -> FSItem -> Bool
nameIs name (Folder folderName _) = name == folderName
nameIs name (File   fileName   _) = name == fileName

x -: f = f x

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Example to work on
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

myDisk :: FSItem  
myDisk = 
    Folder "root"   
        [ File "goat_yelling_like_man.wmv" "baaaaaa"  
        , File "pope_time.avi" "god bless"  
        , Folder "pics"  
            [ File "ape_throwing_up.jpg" "bleargh"  
            , File "watermelon_smash.gif" "smash!!"  
            , File "skull_man(scary).bmp" "Yikes!"  
            ]  
        , File "dijon_poupon.doc" "best mustard"  
        , Folder "programs"  
            [ File "fartwizard.exe" "10gotofart"  
            , File "owl_bandit.dmg" "mov eax, h00t"  
            , File "not_a_virus.exe" "really not a virus"  
            , Folder "source code"  
                [ File "best_hs_prog.hs" "main = print (fix error)"  
                , File "random.hs" "main = print 4"  
                ]  
            ]  
        ]
```

The commands you can use:

```
*Filesystem> let newFocus1 = (myDisk,[]) -: fsTo "programs" -: fsTo "source code"
*Filesystem> let newFocus2 = (myDisk,[]) -: fsTo "pics" -: fsTo "ape_throwing_up.jpg"
```

No matter what I do I always end up with a list with only one Item, so wouldn't it be better to use just `FSCrumb` instead of `[FSCrumb]`?

Comment: It has to be a list, since the zipper is supposed to leave a trail of breadcrumbs; it would be more useful if you provide us with a complete code example that does *not* behave as you expect, that we can run and see what is wrong.

Comment: @typedfern done

Comment: Ran both examples; both of them produce a list of breadcrumbs with two elements; can't see where the problem is...

Comment: To check how many elements the resulting list has, you can do this: ```length $ snd $ (myDisk,[]) -: fsTo "programs" -: fsTo "source code"``` - you'll see it says the list has two elements.

Comment: Yeah, because `FSZipper` consists of two elements, but if you print the length of the list of `FSCrumbs` the answer is in both cases 1
Here's a litte debug helper i wrote:`debug :: FSZipper -> IO ()
debug (item, FSCrumb name ls rs : bs) = do
    putStrLn "name:"
    print name
    putStrLn "ls:"
    mapM_ print ls
    putStrLn "item:"
    print item
    putStrLn "rs:"
    mapM_ print rs
    putStrLn "bs:"
    mapM_ print bs
    putStrLn "length of bs:"
    print $ length bs`

Comment: That command I showed you *does* print the length of the list of FSCrumbs (notice the use of ```snd``` to get the second item, the crumbs list); what command are you using to get that 1?

Comment: I already edited the command an provided it and while I write this I see how stupid I am...
I extract the first element and print the length of the rest of the list....

Comment: Happens to all of us :) In any case, this is the reason why, when asking questions on  stackoverflow, you should always provide a *full* example (in this case, an example that actually prints "1"); this way, we can help you much more effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was simply the method used to obtain the number of breadcrumbs;
a simple (and correct) way is:

```hs
numberOfBreadcrumbs :: FSZipper -> Int
numberOfBreadcrumbs (_, breadcrumbs) = length breadcrumbs
```